# what is equivalent query for /adgroupconversions in marketing api v2.4?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

In facebook marketing API version 2.3, I used following query in Graph Explorer for conversion stats:

/act_ID/adgroupconversions?start_time=2015-09-09&end_time=2015-09-09&aggregate_days=1

and get the following response:

```
[{
      "adgroup_id": "6026929504954",
      "values": [
        {
          "start_time": 1441737000,
          "end_time": 1441823400,
          "conversions": [
            {
              "action_type": "like",
              "object_id": "378877135503478",
              "post_click_1d": 1,
              "post_click_7d": 1,
              "post_click_28d": 1
            },
            {
              "action_type": "link_click",
              "object_id": "930442410346945",
              "post_click_1d": 4,
              "post_click_7d": 4,
              "post_click_28d": 4
            },
            {
              "action_type": "post_like",
              "object_id": "378877135503478",
              "post_click_1d": 15,
              "post_click_7d": 15,
              "post_click_28d": 15
            },
            {
              "action_type": "page_engagement",
              "object_id": "378877135503478",
              "post_click_1d": 16,
              "post_click_7d": 16,
              "post_click_28d": 16
            },
            {
              "action_type": "page_engagement",
              "object_id": "930442410346945",
              "post_click_1d": 4,
              "post_click_7d": 4,
              "post_click_28d": 4
            },
            {
              "action_type": "post_engagement",
              "object_id": "930442410346945",
              "post_click_1d": 4,
              "post_click_7d": 4,
              "post_click_28d": 4
            },
            {
              "action_type": "post_engagement",
              "object_id": "378877135503478",
              "post_click_1d": 15,
              "post_click_7d": 15,
              "post_click_28d": 15
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }]
```

Since, /adgroupconversions is being deprecated in v2.4 and is merged into /insights edge. Does anybody know a way to get this conversions stats data from /insights edge?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the conversion stats by querying `/v2.4/[adgroup-id]/insights`. The fields returned should be the same as the `/adgroupconversions` edge in v2.3.